# implicit declaration of function '_strnicmp' is invalid in C99

Tags: ios, c, xcode

I'm new in iOS

now i counter a problem

```
#define strncasecmp _strnicmp
```

it has a warning:

```
implicit declaration of function '_strnicmp' is invalid in C99
```

and also has error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"__strnicmp", referenced from:
  _AVI_open_input_file in avilib.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Quite simply, your C runtime doesn't have the function `_strnicmp`, which is a [Microsoft-specific function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chd90w8e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), not a standard C function.

You should remove that `#define` and use the function `strncasecmp`, since `strncasecmp` is a [POSIX function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcasecmp.html), and iOS is POSIX-compliant.